DJango rest-framework pagination without settings in REST_FRAMEWORK
I am following pagination help. It has para as

You can also set the pagination class on an individual view by using
the pagination_class attribute. Typically you'll want to use the same
pagination style throughout your API, although you might want to vary
individual aspects of the pagination, such as default or maximum page
size, on a per-view basis.

I set pagination_class in my ViewSet,
from rest_framework import generics

from rest_framework.pagination import LimitOffsetPagination

from my_models.models import Osug

from my_api.serializers.osug import OsugSerializer

class OsugList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Osug.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OsugSerializer
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination

If I use above code, it wont return data in paginated.
when I set REST_FRAMEWORK setting, it start effect.
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100
}

When I set, it will set pagination for all view set, I have 10 views, but I want set pagination only on one view.
Can I set pagination without setting in REST_FRAMEWORK parameter?

Please add code of view

You can set Per View Pagination like this
Per View Pagination (views.py)
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.pagination import LimitOffsetPagination
from my_models.models import Osug
from my_api.serializers.osug import OsugSerializer

class MyLimitOffsetPagination(LimitOffsetPagination):
    default_limit = 10
    max_limit = 100

class OsugList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Osug.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OsugSerializer
    pagination_class = MyLimitOffsetPagination


Do I have to define MyLimitOffsetPagination? I cant use LimitOffsetPagination direct ?

Yes you can use directly

Define MyLimitOffsetPagination just above of your viewset and use at pagination_class = MyLimitOffsetPagination

but directly its not working if I not added REST_FRAMEWORK settings.

Answer is updated please check

so the answer is, I have to override the paginated class and use that overrided class, or I have to add REST_FRAMEWORK settings ?
